# Hibernate and playframework giving IllegalArgumentException ... was not matching type java.util.Map

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.1

When I migrated my application from 2.0.4 to 2.1.0 this exception gets thrown:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [shared.models.Restaurant@f59fc] was not matching type [java.util.Map]]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:128) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [shared.models.Restaurant@f59fc] was not matching type [java.util.Map]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:360) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:364) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:194) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:247) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:603) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
    at shared.dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl$QueryQuery.selectCount(GenericDAOImpl.java:273) ~[na:na]
```

All the modelDao's extends this `GenericDAOImpl`. the method ad line 273 is:

```
    Long selectCount(){
        CriteriaBuilder builder = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<T> root = criteria.from( clazz );
        criteria.select(builder.count(root));
        criteria.where(buildWhere(builder, root));
        //buildSelectWhere(builder, root, criteria);
        return JPA.em().createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
    }
```

The `clazz` variable is a .class of the model of the extending DAO.
I'm kinda lost in what the actual problem is.
In 2.0.4 this worked fine by-the-way.

Comment: I was able do replicate this issue with the Computer-Database-JPA example that came with 2.1.0.

Just insert the following somewhere so it run and you will see the error:

        Company company = Company.findById(1l);
        List<Computer> data = JPA.em()
            .createQuery("from Computer where company = :company")
            .setParameter("company", company)
            .setFirstResult(0)
            .setMaxResults(10)
            .getResultList();

Comment: I have posted it as a issue at github: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/issues/851

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the excellent work of the Play developers, this one has been fixed in version 2.1.2:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/851